# Are there any admin control panel html design which can be used freely for commercial websites?

Tags: html, looking-for-a-script

Are there any admin control panel html design which can be used freely for commercial websites?

Or is there any tutorials on how to create nice looking admin control panel designs using static html / css maybe bit of jquery etc?

Comment: Administering what? The website itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should visit

http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates

I know you asked for FREE, but (in my opinion) you gotta spend a few bucks sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Not likely any good ones.  Sensible admin control panels require a server-side language.  If you're designing an admin control panel's theme, your best bet is to get a pen and a piece of paper and write down what you want it to look like.  Then, create the HTML template.  Then, create the CSS.  Then, add the necessary PHP.

There's a really cut-and-dry, open-source CMS by "Flash Building".  You could probably hint into the PHP behind a 'from-scratch' website by looking at their website.  There's also a channel on Freenode called #css where they have some great step-by-step resources.

Rather than searching for the 'area' of the website, you might consider searching for the design type.  For example: 'panels', 'grid views', etc.  Widdle it down to div-by-div questions, and you'll get a lot further, a lot faster.

Comment: Also, I couldn't comment on your thread cause this is my first answer.  May I ask, what did you mean by 'design' in the first sentence?  There seems to be a grammatical issue.